# Cannot run a HelloWorld on Intellij Idea (java.lang.IllegalAccessError)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I wanted to just run HelloWorld on Intellij Idea which is failed.
Java Version is "9-ea" in my macOS.

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.IllegalAccessError) class com.intellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil (in unnamed module @0x6ecc4cd7) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x6ecc4cd7
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.intellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil (in unnamed module @0x6ecc4cd7) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x6ecc4cd7
    at com.intellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil.setupUnInterruptibleHandle(FileChannelUtil.java:26)
    ......
```

[image]

Comment: Please make sure to use the release JDK version, not ea and update to the latest IntelliJ IDEA version: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html .

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks buddy, if you answered it as an answer and not comment, I would've gratefully marked it as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make sure to use the release JDK version, not `ea` and update to the [latest IntelliJ IDEA version](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).

Comment: why we need to upgrade the IntelliJ Idea ?

Comment: @Kedar9444 Older IntelliJ IDEA versions may not support JDK versions released after that IDE version.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and the solution I've found was to downgrade my Java version (JDK) from 16 to 11. Then, it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Language Level was not matching with JDK version i.e. 17. After [downloading latest IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html?utm_source=product&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=IC&utm_content=2019.3#version20193) I got language levels to 20.

File > Project Structure
[image]