# Can't Run Spring boot application once downgraded jdk version from 11 to 8 using IntelliJIdea

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I can't run my java project once downgrade the JDK version from 11 to 8.
Spring Boot maven Project and using IntelliJIdea.
I've changed project settings on IntelliJIdea.
[error-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvyTV.png)

and project setting screenshot
[setting-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10DLb.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554377/cannot-run-a-helloworld-on-intellij-idea-java-lang-illegalaccesserror

Comment: This is a intellij problem. Delete .idea directory and *.iml file and re open the project

Comment: oh , great @SimonMartinelli. it works to me.

Comment: please reply to this post, then I can make your comment as answer thank you.

Comment: That's always the hammer that helps ;_9

Comment: @SusanMustafa I used the way already before to post this error, but it didn't work for me. anyway thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete .idea directoray form your root path of project.
also need to remove .iml file if there is.
This problems causing in IJ tool.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Intellij problem.

Delete `.idea` directory and `*.iml` file and re open the project